# Inkscape svg to pdf crops too much

Tags: pdf, svg, inkscape

There is a slight error when exporting an `svg` file to `pdf`: the right margin of the plot is cropped too much (see the missing vertical line for completing the box area of the plot - this is how the pdf looks like):
[image]

Here is the `svg` file (the box area is complete - the right margin line exists):
[image]

I'm exporting with this command:

> inkscape filename.svg --export-area-drawing --export-pdf=filename.pdf

I also did a test and manually exported the file from the GUI but it gave the same result. Is there a way to fix it? Like adding some padding? Can it be done from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting/linking the svg file could help. Tried to download the complete image, transform it as vector and export it as pdf, worked fine.

wich version of Inkscape are you using ? It is up to date ? ( mine, that is working is version 0.48.4 r9939 on Ubuntu ).

A solution I use when facing export problems is create a empty rectangle around my draw, set it to no border and no fill, and then apply "File" > "Document Properties" > "Resize page to content" > "Resize page to drawing or selection" with no object selected. Re-export.

Try to make a "Vacuums Defs" to clean the svg file before export.

Good luck to you!

EDIT : command line equivalent to this manipulation can be achieved by adding "--export-area-drawing --vacuum-defs" as command line parameters.

Comment: I would prefer a command line solution to this problem because I'd like to use it in a script.

Comment: a quick look at "inkscape --help" give me results. Answer edited.